# How do I pass down function from parent component to child component in React

Tags: reactjs

Currently I am trying to split up the app in separate components to make it more readable and testable. But now I faced an issue, which is the general function in the parent component. How do I call the general onChange function from separate components. Because there are multiple input fields that do the same, so therefore I want to make a reusable function in parent component, that can be called from the child component.

```js
// child component 
export default class Name extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }
    
    state = {
        name: '',
        nameErrorMessage: ''
    }

    checkName = (name: string) => {
        const re = /[^a-zA-Z]/;
        const checkValidation = re.test(name);
        const nameRequirements = !checkValidation && name.length > 1;
            
        if(!nameRequirements) {
            this.setState({ nameErrorMessage: 'name contains numbers, symbols or is too short (min length of 2 letters)', nameBoolean: false });
        } else {
            this.setState({ nameErrorMessage: '', nameBoolean: true });
        } 
    }
    
    handleNameChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        const getName = event.target.value;
        const getNameValid = this.checkName(getName);
        return getNameValid;
    }

    onChange = () => {
        this.props.parentMethod();
    }

    render() {
        return (
        <div className="two-columns two-columns-child column-block">
            <label className="label-customized">First name</label><br/>
            <input 
                name="name"
                className="input-customized"
                type="text" 
                value={this.state.name} 
                onBlur={this.handleNameChange} 
                onChange={this.onChange} 
                placeholder="Enter first name" 
            />
            <br/>
            <span className="error-message">{this.state.nameErrorMessage}</span>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
    
    // parent component 
    
    
     onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    let onChangeName:any = event.target.getAttribute('name');
    this.setState({[onChangeName]: event.target.value })
  }
  
    return (
      <div className="App">
          <form onSubmit={this.checkForm}>
            <Name/>
         </form>
        </div>
     )
```

Comment: You could move the checkName function to a separate file and then import it in both the child and parent components. Instead of having it mutate state, just return a boolean if it's good or bad input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**PARENT COMPONENT**

pass `onChange` as property to the child component
    ...

```
return (
    <div className="App">
        <form onSubmit={this.checkForm}>
           <Name onChange={this.onChange}/>
        </form>
    </div>
)
```

**CHILD COMPONENT**

call the passed prop when `onChange` is called for the input

```
return  <div className="two-columns two-columns-child column-block">
            <label className="label-customized">First name</label><br/>
            <input 
                name="name"
                className="input-customized"
                type="text" 
                value={this.state.name} 
                onBlur={this.handleNameChange} 
                onChange={e => this.props.onChange(e)} 
                placeholder="Enter first name" 
            />
            <br/>
            <span className="error-message">{this.state.nameErrorMessage}</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: but it seems in my case that I cannot pass it to the value attribute....